# CSS rounded triangle issue

Tags: css, sass

I want to design something like this. [image]

I have created it using following code:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: white;
border-top: solid 2px red;
border-left: solid 2px red;
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
border-right: solid 2px transparent;
border-bottom: solid 2px transparent;
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Here is the codepen of the code I have been playing with: https://codepen.io/ashesh-test/pen/WNGzKLO

But the problem now is, I have got some buttons inside the `div` and it looks like this when scrolling inside the `div` when change in the background color. I have tried with z-index for the contents and other ways but no luck:
[image]

So, how can I remove the bottom half of the triangle or is there any other neat way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear how you change the background color... On scroll? Button click?

Whatever, that sure is via JS.

So why not set the SAME background color to ALL first child divs of `.wrapper`?

*NICE rounded triangle by the way!*

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper>div").forEach(function(div){
   div.style.background = "#aae8c4";
  });
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 25px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: green;
}

.list-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: solid 2px red;
  border-left: solid 2px red;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-right: solid 2px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 2px transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list-box">
  </div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<button>Change my color!</button>
```

---

**EDIT**

Interestingly... I spent way more time on the "random color generator" than the rest....

*lol*

But here, you have the button inside the `.wrapper` div... And 2 of those.
The concept still remains the same.

There is some insignificant changes: the `.triangle` position in DOM, so it now is the first child... And its top position.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    let randomHexColor = `#${randomHex()}${randomHex()}${randomHex()}`
    console.log(randomHexColor);

    e.target.closest(".wrapper").querySelectorAll(".list-box, .triangle").forEach(function(div) {
      div.style.background = randomHexColor;
    });
  });
})

function randomHex() {
  let randomColorPat = (Math.random() * 255).toString(16).split(".")[0]
  if (randomColorPat.length !== 2) {
    return "0" + randomColorPat
  } else {
    return randomColorPat
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 25px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.list-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: solid 2px red;
  border-left: solid 2px red;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-right: solid 2px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 2px transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="list-box">
    <button>Change my color!</button>
  </div>

</div>

<br>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="list-box">
    <button>Change my color!</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

**Another edit**

Maybe what you look for is how to clip the inner part....

So I found that `clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%);` would work quite fine. Below is the first example where I "force" the `.triangle` to be white just to show the bottom half is not showing anymore...:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper>div").forEach(function(div){
   div.style.background = "#aae8c4";
  });
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 25px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: green;
}

.list-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  background: white !important;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%);
  top: 25px;
  left: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: solid 2px red;
  border-left: solid 2px red;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-right: solid 2px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 2px transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list-box">
  </div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<button>Change my color!</button>
```

Comment: What I mean is I have got buttons inside the div which has different background than the div so, on different background, the bottom half of the triangle shows up as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: I edited with a fun thing... but... Usure it's what you asked. lol

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Got it working now though its not perfect.

Comment: This is where I got at the end! But you don't need extra border styles. Just a single border style should do the trick.

Comment: Again, nice triangle. I probably will use that in some future project. ;)

Answer (score 0):

One line solutions on `.triangle` class :P

Option 1. Play with gradients.

```
background: linear-gradient(135deg, green 0% 50%, transparent 50%);
```

Option 2. [CSS/clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```
clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see ho you can make it work with either options. It takes back to square 1 of my current issue.